# oledbcommand excel insert syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
   string strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + firstSheetName + "(Date, Market, Source, Commodity, Frequency, Price, Report_Type, MISC, Breeds, Age_Group, Gender, Grade) VALUES ('Beth', 'Hart','Beth', 'Hart','Beth', 'Hart','Beth', 'Hart','Beth', 'Hart','Beth')";

 OleDbCommand OleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, oconn);

   OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after `"INSERT INTO " + firstSheetName + "(Date,`

to

`"INSERT INTO " + firstSheetName + " (Date,`

Another thing that I have noticed is that you have 12 column values and only 11 data values.  You'll need to add the 12th data value.

Comment: no this also doesn't solves the problem . $ are allowed in the name?

Comment: Change your query to `"INSERT INTO [" + firstSheetName + "] (Date,` etc.

Comment: Surely `INTO [" + firstSheetName + "$]`

Comment: @Remou: I'm under the impression that `firstSheetName` equals something like `MySheet$`

Comment: Good point, but I suspect it does not. (I should have added an @ for the OP, because the comment was much more meant for @mazhar)

Comment: ok wow putting [] in columns solves the problem "INSERT INTO " + firstSheetName + "([Date],[Market]